# Determine median and quartiles using columnar data in Snowflake

Tags: sql, statistics, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a way to calculate the median, first and third quartiles from a data set based on certain parameters. I also would like to use these values for future coding.

Here is what the data looks like:

| ID | Country | Gold Level | Silver Level | Diamond Level | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | Y | N | Y | 0.1 |
| 234 | B | N | N | Y |  |
| 365 | C | Y | Y | Y | 0.003 |
| 234 | D | N | N | N | 0.07 |
| 245 | A | Y | Y | N | 0.65 |
| 374 | B | Y | N | N | 0.87 |
| 937 | D | N | N | Y | 0.55 |

What I am looking for is to find  the median, first and third quartiles based on country and level. So, provide me the median, first and third quartiles for country A and Gold Level = 'Y', find me median, first and third quartiles for Country A and Silver Level = 'Y', etc.

Also in some cases, as you see in row 2, there is a blank value. I would like to replace that value with 0

Perhaps the better output would look something like this:

| Country | Level | Median | 1 Quadrant | 3 Quadrant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Gold | 0.08 | 0.075 | 0.2 |
| A | Silver | 0.2 | 0.01 | 0.5 |
| B | Gold | 0.07 | 0.079 | 0.4 |

Comment: You can use `PERCENTILE_CONT` function in snowflake

Comment: The query can be :

`SELECT
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COALESCE(Value, 0)) AS Median,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COALESCE(Value, 0)) AS First_Quartile,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COALESCE(Value, 0)) AS Third_Quartile
FROM your_table
WHERE Country = 'A' AND "Gold Level" = 'Y';`

Comment: Thank you! This works, but is there a way I can bring in all the country/level combinations into one table?

Comment: Looks like those are already in one table. Did you mean a single column for Gold, Silver and Diamond Level ?

Comment: The output in your suggestion above is only for instances where country = A and Gold Level = Y. I would also like to have the output where Country = b and gold level = Y, etc. in the same output. Also, I noticed that when I used your query the same value was calculated for each ID. I require the result to be per ID.

Comment: To get the median, first and third quartiles based on different combinations of country and level for each ID, you can use the GROUP BY clause in above query.

Can you please check my modified answer below ?

Comment: Please let me know, if your expected result is different than the result of the query in the answer

Comment: Apologies - having the values by ID doesn't make sense. Rather I'm looking to get the median, first quartile and third quartile by each combination of country and level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251932/discussion-between-tushar-and-a-morell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/percentile_cont) function in snowflake

The query would be :

```
SELECT
  Country,
  "Gold Level",
  "Silver Level",
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COALESCE(Value, 0)) AS Median,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COALESCE(Value, 0)) AS First_Quartile,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COALESCE(Value, 0)) AS Third_Quartile
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  Country,
  "Gold Level",
  "Silver Level";
```